# Data Migration from a custom database to Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, migration, data-migration

I am still exploring the topic of migration and would like to know what are the best methods to migrate from a custom written PHP/MySQL system to Drupal 7.

The data that needs to be migrated is in three tables (Journals, Journal Issues and Issue Articles).

The organization publishes several journals, each journal has several issues and each issue has several articles.

This is the data structure:

Journal has: title/description/language/abstract
Issue has : title/journal_id/issue_number/real_issue_number/quarter/year/volume_year/volume_issue_number
article has: title/author/abstract/section/issue_number/pdf_file/featured/tags

Should I use the [migration module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate), the [feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) or should I write my own PHP script to migrate data to a custom created content type ? Any tutorials which describes how to migrate data from a database to Drupal (Not just upgrading).

Thanks!

Comment: I have used the feeds module a couple of times to import a database dump in CSV format into D7. It worked fine except that there was some issues with multiple relationships.

Comment: I didn't note that I should accept answers, I used to vote them up... Thank for the note ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this depends on how good your knowledge of coding in Drupal is; I always write my own solution for an import because I like to have full control over the quality of the incoming data (especially for fields that contain HTML, I like to ensure the code is correct and strip out any tags/attributes I don't want to keep).

Using the migrate module would involve a small learning curve which I don't think is strictly necessary if you're comfortable with creating content in code, although it is an extremely powerful module and I'd recommend [reading the documentation](http://drupal.org/node/415260) to see if it's something you want to use.

Similarly the feeds module will require a small bit of extra reading/learning if you want to use it programatically (see [the documentation](http://drupal.org/node/622700)). But, if you can fully trust that the data you're importing is of a sufficient quality then I think the feeds UI would be the easiest way to get your content in.